# Best Practice to add empty item at top of ComboBox (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I'm trying to put an empty item at top of the combo box. I did that with following code

```
List<tbDesignation> comboList = db.tbDesignations.ToList();
comboList.Insert(0, new tbDesignation() { Id = -1, Name = "(None)" });
```

This code works perfectly fine. But there is one problem. Suppose user doesn't select `Designation`, then default selection would be `(None)`. Once user saves the record of `Staff`(which ask for Designation), this empty entry of `Designation` also saved to database.

`Designation` Table before saving.

[image: Designation table Before Saving]

`Designation` Table After Saving

[image: Designation Table After Saving]

`Staff` Table After Saving

[image: Staff Table After Saving]

This is how it looks while displaying in DataGrid (It's weird. It was supposed to be blank).

[image]

How do I stop entity framework to save empty record of Designation?
OR
Is there any better approach to add an empty item at top of the ComboBox?

**Note:** User must be allowed to select empty item whenever needed.

Comment: Where is your code that saves the designation into the database?

Comment: Can you show what you expect to be save in database and then show the code how you saving data

Comment: I call db.SavesChanges() on Save button of Staff

Comment: db is an object of Database Context

Comment: Check first if you can avoid adding of the dummy element to a combobox. It could be one of the properties or datastructure or even `null` as a combobox item. Depending on your current situation. Otherwise you would have to come through all changed elements and replace `-1` item with `null`

Comment: I do not believe this is really an EF related issue. Input validation within your UI should prevent the users submitting the value of -1. To preserve your domain integrity within your database, setup constraints, being a list of acceptable values or referential integrity against another table of acceptable values. Most databases platforms support these features.

Answer (score 0):

When the code saves the Staff record make sure to only add the Designation object if the ID is not -1.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Entity Framework saves every list which is changed

Comment: You could use a different class in your list object such as: 
List<DesignationModel> comboList = db.tbDesignations.Select(d => new DesignationModel() { Id = d.Id, Name = d.Name }).ToList();   where DesignationModel is a new class you create with matching properties.  That way you won't add an extra record to the tbDesignations table unintentionally when you call SaveChanges().  You'll also have to modify your related code accordingly.